# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 128

Tags: ios, obfuscation, code-access-security

Can any one say what is the cause of the error.I am trying to `obfuscate` my project. I follow below script to execute with change in project name, scheme etc. When i execute the `shell script` error occurring.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard/master/contrib/obfuscate_project

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

echo_and_run git reset --hard

echo_and_run git clean -fdx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script uses `git` and you are running it from a non-`git` directory.

I would recommend commenting-out the `git` commands.